# How to change the position of Crystal report dynamically?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working with crystal report which has two sub reports. I need to change the positions of theses sub reports dynamically.

Could any help me in this portion?

Answer (score 2):

1. Place your 2 subreports in separate subsections (i.e. 1 subreport in GH1a and the other in GH1b)
2. Go into your Section Expert and enter an appropriate formula to suppress each subreport based on your condition.